# Summarizing data: Error in summarize() across() all_of() dynamic_list_of_vars => Selections can't have missing values

Tags: r, dplyr, na, summarize, across

**TL;DR:** `summarize(across(all_of(vars_to_sum), ~ sum(., na.rm=TRUE)))` requires a *non NA* list of `vars_to_sum`, while I'm working inside a function and the user will sometimes ask for no variable to be summarized by a sum. The `summarize()` includes other `across()` and I'm not sure it is solvable by a simple `if()`.

At least that what I think the problem is...

---

Hi!

I'm working on a project that involves quite a bit of data management/engineering, and there's one step that I struggle with. I'll replicate the problem on fake data.

I'm working on hospital stays. I started from relational databases, and I'm slowly summarizing the information in a format that fits my needs. Where my problem starts, the data will look something like this :

```
df <- data.frame(
patient_id = c("Anne","Bryan","Bryan","Charlotte","Charlotte","Denis","Denis","Denis"),
entry_date = as.POSIXt("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-25"),
exit_date = as.POSIXt("2020-01-10", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-10", "2020-03-10", "2020-04-10", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-20", "2020-06-10"),
entry_mode = c("home","home","transfer","home","home","transfer",NA,"transfer"),
exit_mode = c("death","transfer","home","discharged","home","death",NA,"transfer"),
drug_A = c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0),
drug_B = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1),
drug_C = c(1,2,5,1,0,0,1,0)
)
```

*N.B*: the database will have plenty more `drug_xxx` variables

My goal here is to develop a function that would

(1) identify patients that did several stays in a short period of time (started a hospital stay soon after the exit of another one, *N.B:* overlapping stays also exist), since we will consider that all such stays are related to the same medical issue (let's say cardiac arrest). If several hospitals/wards/doctors/... notify a cardiac arrest from the same person several days in a row, it's treated as 1 cardiac arrest, followed by several stays/consultations/... all related to the same cardiac arrest.

(2) summarizing the info of nearby stays by maxing the variables that should be maxed (defined by user), summing what should be summed, considering the earliest or latest datapoint when appropriate, and keeping the rest untouched

The function would consider the following arguments:

- df, a dataframe
- individual_id, a string indicating the name of the variable that identifies individuals
- entry_date
- exit_date
- allowed_dist, the max distance between the exit date of a stay and the entry date of another one
- vars_to_max, names of variables to be maxed
- vars_to_sum, names of variables to be summed
- vars_to_earliest, names of variables for which the earliest info is of interest
- vars_to_latest, names of variables for which the latest info is of interest

Ideally, the function should work even if var_to_xxx arguments are NA, implying there's no variable to be sumrized this way on this occasion.

[EDIT: I initially shared my functional function, mixing dplyr and for-loops, but I think it just made the post less readable, so here goes a function that almost work and that needs fixing]

```
aggregate_stays <- function (df, individual_id, date_entry, date_exit, allowed_dist=0, vars_to_earliest=NA, vars_to_latest=NA, vars_to_sum=NA, vars_to_max=NA){
  
  require("lubridate",quietly=TRUE)
  require("dplyr",quietly=TRUE)
  
  # Distinguishing between single stays and multiple stays
  df_single_stays <- df %>%
    group_by(!!sym(individual_id)) %>%
    filter(n() == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  df_multiple_stays <- df %>%
    group_by(!!sym(individual_id)) %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  # Summarizing multiple stays according to the arguments of the function
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    arrange(!!sym(individual_id), !!sym(date_entry)) %>% # Ordering the individuals and stays
    group_by(!!sym(individual_id)) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cumsum(!!sym(date_entry) - lag(!!sym(date_exit), default = first(!!sym(date_exit))) > allowed_dist)) %>% # Checking if nearby stays
    group_by(!!sym(individual_id), wholestay_id) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cur_group_id()) %>% # Creating the index of "big stays"
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(wholestay_id) %>%
    summarize(wholestay_entry = min(!!sym(date_entry)),
              wholestay_exit = max(!!sym(date_exit)),
              across(all_of(vars_to_earliest), ~ .[which.min(!!sym(date_entry))]),
              across(all_of(vars_to_latest), ~ .[which.max(!!sym(date_exit))]),
              across(all_of(vars_to_sum), ~ sum(., na.rm=TRUE)),
              across(all_of(vars_to_max), ~ max(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  
  # Removing the `wholestay_id` variable that was not asked by user
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    dplyr::select(-wholestay_id)
  
  df_final <- bind_rows(df_multiple_stays,df_single_stays)
  
  return(df_final)
}
```

But it doesn't seem to enjoy NA as argument for vars_to_xxx arguments

```
df2 <- aggregate_stays_wip(df = df,
                           individual_id = "patient_id",
                           date_entry = "entry_date",
                           date_exit = "exit_date",
                           allowed_dist = 10,
                           vars_to_sum = "drug_C",
                           vars_to_max = c("drug_A","drug_B"),
                           vars_to_earliest = "entry_mode",
                           vars_to_latest = c("patient_id","exit_mode"))
```

works fine

but

```
df3 <- aggregate_stays(df = df,
                       individual_id = "patient_id",
                       date_entry = "entry_date",
                       date_exit = "exit_date",
                       allowed_dist = 10,
                       vars_to_sum = NA,
                       vars_to_max = c("drug_A","drug_B","drug_C"),
                       vars_to_earliest = "entry_mode",
                       vars_to_latest = c("patient_id","exit_mode"))
```

returns

```
Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(all_of(vars_to_sum), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Selections can't have missing values.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If you have any way to solve this, I'd love to hear it!

Best,
an epidemiologist who whish he'd be better at coding.

Comment: i get dizzy when i see someone mixing tidyverse with for-loops. unless you are doing simulations, why use for-loop? ie it seems groupby should do the trick for your for-loop

Comment: I get that the first approach is "wrong", I was just trying to translate in code how I would tackle the problem in my head.

Probably shouldn't have include it at all. The second half of the post should have been enough : how do I write the `summarize(across(all_of(vector) ~ ... `

in a way that accepts the possibility of `vector <- NA`

?

Comment: I think a fix would be to change the `vars_to_sum` variable to an empty string (i.e., `if(any(is.na(vars_to_sum))) vars_to_sum <- ''`) if it is NA, then change `all_of()` to `any_of()` to allow potentially incorrect column names to be ignored instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `NULL` instead and it then skips over that line of the summarise call.

You can also perhaps make things easier by passing `NULL` as default and using tidy evaluation to avoid having to do quotes:

```r
library(tidyverse)

aggregate_things <- function(
      data,
      vars_to_sum = NULL,
      vars_to_mean = NULL,
      vars_to_max = NULL
) {
  
  data |> 
    summarise(
      across({{vars_to_sum}}, sum),
      across({{vars_to_mean}}, mean),
      across({{vars_to_max}}, max),
    )
}

iris |> 
  aggregate_things(vars_to_sum = c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width),
                   vars_to_max = c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#> 1        876.5       458.6          6.9         2.5
```

### Modifying your code to take `NULL`s

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  patient_id = c("Anne","Bryan","Bryan","Charlotte","Charlotte","Denis","Denis","Denis"),
  entry_date = ymd("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-05-05", "2020-05-25"),
  exit_date = ymd("2020-01-10", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-10", "2020-03-10", "2020-04-10", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-20", "2020-06-10"),
  entry_mode = c("home","home","transfer","home","home","transfer",NA,"transfer"),
  exit_mode = c("death","transfer","home","discharged","home","death",NA,"transfer"),
  drug_A = c("0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0"),
  drug_B = c("0","1","1","0","0","0","1","1"),
  drug_C = c("1","2","5","1","0","0","1","0")
) |> 
  mutate(across(starts_with("drug"), as.integer))


aggregate_stays <-
  function (df,
            individual_id,
            date_entry,
            date_exit,
            allowed_dist = 0,
            vars_to_earliest = NULL,
            vars_to_latest = NULL,
            vars_to_sum = NULL,
            vars_to_max = NULL) {
    
    require("lubridate",quietly=TRUE)
    require("dplyr",quietly=TRUE)

  # Distinguishing between single stays and multiple stays
  df_single_stays <- df %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    filter(n() == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  df_multiple_stays <- df %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>%
    ungroup()

  # Summarizing multiple stays according to the arguments of the function
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    arrange({{individual_id}}, {{date_entry}}) %>% # Ordering the individuals and stays
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cumsum({{date_entry}} - lag({{date_exit}}, default = first({{date_exit}})) > allowed_dist)) %>% # Checking if nearby stays
    group_by({{individual_id}}, wholestay_id) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cur_group_id()) %>% # Creating the index of "big stays"
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(wholestay_id) %>%
    summarize(wholestay_entry = min({{date_entry}}),
              wholestay_exit = max({{date_exit}}),
              across({{vars_to_earliest}}, ~ .[which.min({{date_entry}})]),
              across({{vars_to_latest}}, ~ .[which.max({{date_exit}})]),
              across({{vars_to_sum}}, ~ sum(., na.rm=TRUE)),
              across({{vars_to_max}}, ~ max(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  
  # Removing the `wholestay_id` variable that was not asked by user
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    dplyr::select(-wholestay_id)
  
  df_final <- bind_rows(df_multiple_stays,df_single_stays)
  
  return(df_final)
}

aggregate_stays(df = df,
                    individual_id = patient_id,
                    date_entry = entry_date,
                    date_exit = exit_date,
                    allowed_dist = 10,
                    vars_to_sum = drug_C,
                    vars_to_max = c(drug_A,drug_B),
                    vars_to_earliest = entry_mode,
                    vars_to_latest = c(patient_id,exit_mode))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 10
#>   wholestay_entry wholestay_exit entry_mode patient_id exit_mode  drug_C drug_A
#>   <date>          <date>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <int>  <int>
#> 1 2020-02-01      2020-02-10     home       Bryan      home            7      1
#> 2 2020-03-01      2020-03-10     home       Charlotte  discharged      1      1
#> 3 2020-04-01      2020-04-10     home       Charlotte  home            0      0
#> 4 2020-05-01      2020-06-10     transfer   Denis      transfer        1      1
#> 5 NA              NA             home       Anne       death           1      0
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: drug_B <int>, entry_date <date>, exit_date <date>

aggregate_stays(df = df,
                individual_id = patient_id,
                date_entry = entry_date,
                date_exit = exit_date,
                allowed_dist = 10,
                vars_to_max = c(drug_A,drug_B,drug_C),
                vars_to_earliest = entry_mode,
                vars_to_latest = c(patient_id,exit_mode))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 10
#>   wholestay_entry wholestay_exit entry_mode patient_id exit_mode  drug_A drug_B
#>   <date>          <date>         <chr>      <chr>      <chr>       <int>  <int>
#> 1 2020-02-01      2020-02-10     home       Bryan      home            1      1
#> 2 2020-03-01      2020-03-10     home       Charlotte  discharged      1      0
#> 3 2020-04-01      2020-04-10     home       Charlotte  home            0      0
#> 4 2020-05-01      2020-06-10     transfer   Denis      transfer        1      1
#> 5 NA              NA             home       Anne       death           0      0
#> # ℹ 3 more variables: drug_C <int>, entry_date <date>, exit_date <date>
```

This should now take your data and give the intended result, with the added advantage of if you pipe your dataframe into the function in RStudio then tab autocomplete will look up the columns in your dataframe for you and pass them as unquoted column names.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much, @andy_baxter !

That does indeed work on the example data! I just needed to make a slight variation for it to work on my actual data.

Posting here the function I'm using now

```
aggregate_stays <- function (df,individual_id,date_entry,date_exit,allowed_dist=0,vars_to_earliest=NULL,vars_to_latest=NULL,vars_to_sum=NULL,vars_to_max=NULL){
  
  require("lubridate",quietly=TRUE)
  require("dplyr",quietly=TRUE)
  
  # Distinguishing between single stays and multiple stays
  df_single_stays <- df %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    filter(n() == 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  df_multiple_stays <- df %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    filter(n() > 1) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    arrange({{individual_id}}, {{date_entry}}) %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cumsum({{date_entry}} - lag({{date_exit}}, default = first({{date_exit}})) > allowed_dist)) %>%
    group_by({{individual_id}}, wholestay_id) %>%
    mutate(wholestay_id = cur_group_id()) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(wholestay_id) %>%
    summarize(wholestay_entry = min({{date_entry}}),
              wholestay_exit = max({{date_exit}}),
              across(all_of({{vars_to_earliest}}), ~ .[which.min({{date_entry}})]),
              across(all_of({{vars_to_latest}}), ~ .[which.max({{date_exit}})]),
              across(all_of({{vars_to_sum}}), ~ sum(., na.rm=TRUE)),
              across(all_of({{vars_to_max}}), ~ max(., na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  
  # Removing the `wholestay_id` variable that was not asked by user
  df_multiple_stays <- df_multiple_stays %>%
    dplyr::select(-wholestay_id)
  
  df_final <- bind_rows(df_multiple_stays,df_single_stays)
  
  return(df_final)
}
```

The only difference is that `{{vars_to_xxx}}` are now inside a `all_of()`. This is due to the fact that I have plenty of `drug_xxx` variables, and will be feeding them to the function as a vector containing their names.

So in the end, calling the function looks like this, now :
(*NB:* `allowed_dist` is asked to the user earlier on. The names of the numeric and boolean variables cannot be known in advance, but I automatically tag them with a prefix earlier in the pipeline. The variable identifying a person, the entry/exit dates are always the same.)

```
vars_to_max <- c(names(df)[grep("prefix_for_numeric_variables_",names(df))])
vars_to_sum <- c(names(df)[grep("prefix_for_boolean_variables_",names(df))])
vars_to_earliest <- "entry_mode"
vars_to_latest <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% c("patient_id","entry_date","exit_date",vars_to_sum,vars_to_max,vars_to_earliest)]
aggregate_stays(df = df,
                individual_id = patient_id,
                date_entry = entry_date,
                date_exit = exit_date,
                allowed_dist = allowed_dist,
                vars_to_max = vars_to_max,
                vars_to_sum = vars_to_sum,
                vars_to_earliest = vars_to_earliest,
                vars_to_latest = vars_to_latest)
```

And processing nationwide data went from a 5 min task to a 10 sec task !
(well, at least this part of the process)

Thanks again!

Comment: Looks good! An alternative to pre-generating a vector of names and passing via `all_of` is to use tidy select, so `vars_to_max = starts_with("prefix_for_numeric_variables")` in your function call will tell the function to select the correct variables within the summarise statement. But that's just a fun extra possibility :). Though would make your excluding call to `vars_to_latest` more complex than your current method of pre-defining character vectors. Anyway, happy coding!